# Get min max from the list inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am trying to get min and max (output as list) of a list inside a list. But it is not working as expected. Here is what I have so far.

```
import functools

# Input
raw_data = [
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 17],
    [3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 37]
]

min_max_rows = list(map(lambda x: (min(x), max(x)), raw_data))
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (min(x), max(y)), min_max_rows)

print(result) # Prints (2,37) instead of (0,37)
```

Comment: Hint: The elements of `min_max_rows` are tuples, not numbers.  What does it mean to take the minimum or maximum of a list of tuples?

Comment: You have done great, print(list(result)) or list(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (min(x), max(y)), min_max_rows))

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten your list of list first:

```
flat = [item for sublist in raw_data for item in sublist]
max_item = max(flat)
min_item = min(flat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
min_val = min(min(raw_data))
max_val = max(max(raw_data))
min_max_list = [min_val,max_val]
```

Edit:

There is a problem with this which I apparently overlooked. The `min_val` contains the minimum value of that row that starts with the smallest value. Likewise for `max_val` so instead, I propose a different solution

```
temp1 = []
temp2 = []
for x in raw_data:
    temp1.append(min(x))
    temp2.append(max(x))
min_max_list = [min(temp1),max(temp2)]
```

Comment: Works for the OP's sample, but not `raw_data=[[2,0,9],[4,3,4],[1,2,3]]`.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy approach - it should be much faster on bigger lists:

```
import numpy as np

In [74]: a = np.asarray(raw_data)

In [75]: a
Out[75]:
array([[ 2,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 17],
       [ 3,  4,  3,  4,  5,  6, 37]])

In [76]: min_max_list = [a.min(), a.max()]

In [77]: min_max_list
Out[77]: [0, 37]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be closer to what you want:

```
result = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: (min(*a, *b), max(*a, *b)), min_max_rows)
```

Have the max and min function evaluate explicitly on two arguments which are your tuples from the list. the * is needed to unpack the tuples.